# Minimum Distance between a kitten and a puppy moving on a coordinate plane

Tags: optimization, parametric

At time $t= 0$, the kitten is at $(1,0)$ and the puppy is at $(-1,0)$. The kitten starts walking counterclockwise along the unit circle, and the puppy runs right along the $x$-axis. If the puppy's speed is always twice the kitten's, what will the shortest distance ever between the two be?

I've been trying to create parametric equations for the two, and see if I can use the pythagorean theorem with their $x$-coordinates, but wasn't able to get anywhere with finding the minimum distance.

Puppy: $x= t$, $y = 0$
Kitten: $x = \cos(\frac{-t}{2})$, $y = \sin(\frac{-t}{2})$ [since counterclockwise movement]

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to elaborate on your difficulty writing parametric equations for the position of the puppy and the kitten.  Can you write a parametric equation for either?  For both?  If so, what are they?  Is your difficulty finding the minimum distance once you have your equations in hand?

Comment: It seems like you have the right approach! Once you have the equation for the relative distance with respect with time, use calculus analysis to find the minimum (remember that t>0!)

Comment: Are you allowed to use a calculator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first make 2 little equations for the position of the puppy and kitten with respect to time. Let's do the kitten first (it's a bit harder). If imagine the kitten is moving a distance of 1 unit per second (or whatever time unit) over the circle surface, then the formula for it's angle relative to the origin point will be $\frac{t}{2\pi}$ in radians. So, to find the $x$ value at some time you take $\cos(\frac{t}{2\pi})$ and to find the $y$ value you take $\sin(\frac{t}{2\pi})$. Now the puppy is easier, the y value will always equal $0$, but the $x$ value is simply given with: $f(t) = 2t-1$ (moving right at a rate of 2 units per second to the right from a starting location of $-1$). Now to find the distance between them we use the Pythagorean theorem:

$$d(t) = \sqrt{(puppy\text{ }x - kitten\text{ }x)^2 + (puppy\text{ }y - kitten\text{ }y)^2}$$

Plugging in the formulas we just found:
$$d(t) = \sqrt{\left (2t-1- \cos\frac{t}{2\pi}\right )^2 + \left (0 - \sin \frac{t}{2\pi} \right )^2}$$

Now you have a formula for the distance between the two as a function of time. Plug this into your calculator and find the time when the distance between the two is minimized. If you can't use your calculator find this point by taking the derivative of this formula. Plug this time into the formula again to find the distance between the two.

Comment: Have *you* tried taking the derivative?

Comment: In the last formula for d(t), it should be (2t-1... instead of (2x-1

Comment: @DavidG.Stork It wouldn't be too difficult to do so but the question never stated if a calculator is allowed or not. I also wanted to leave some work for him to do in this case, since this seems to be a homework question. If he comments he needs to find the derivative and is struggling I can do that.

Comment: @fredq Oops, thanks. Missed that.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The derivative is not that difficult to calculate, but granted, finding the zeroes is pretty hard without some software. I think it it the easiest way to go, though.

Comment: @fredq True, that's why I assume a calculator of some form is allowed, finding a zero without one seems to be beyond the difficulty of this problem.

Comment: A calculator is allowed for this problem, thanks for your solution!

Comment: I got that the minimum was at (0.998, 0.15703) with a calculator, but i'm still curious how to find the zeroes by hand. If anyone's able to do that I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @user978757 You'd have to find the derivative of the function (not sure if you know what that is but basically a formula for finding the slope of the function), and then solve for when the derivative equals zero. If you do that though you'd find the derivative is really big, and finding when it equals zero would be incredibly hard. Probably the easiest way to do it by hand would be approximating when it equals zero with Newton's method, which is actually exactly how the calculator does it. You can find an article on that here: https://sites.und.edu/timothy.prescott/apex/web/apex.Ch4.S4.html